# Convert the json value in excel through Powershell

Tags: azure, cost-management

```
$filepath = $PSScriptRoot
Set-Location $filepath

$lastmonth = $true
function GetAccessToken
{
    $azureCmdlet = get-command -Name Get-AZContext -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($azureCmdlet -eq $null)
    {
        $null = Import-Module AZ -ErrorAction Stop;
    }
    $AzureContext = & "Get-AZContext" -ErrorAction Stop;
    $authenticationFactory = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Factories.AuthenticationFactory
    if ((Get-Variable -Name PSEdition -ErrorAction Ignore) -and ('Core' -eq $PSEdition))
    {
        [Action[string]]$stringAction = { param ($s) }
        $serviceCredentials = $authenticationFactory.GetServiceClientCredentials($AzureContext, $stringAction)
    }
    else
    {
        $serviceCredentials = $authenticationFactory.GetServiceClientCredentials($AzureContext)
    }
    
    # We can't get a token directly from the service credentials. Instead, we need to make a dummy message which we will ask
    # the serviceCredentials to add an auth token to, then we can take the token from this message.
    $message = New-Object System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage -ArgumentList @([System.Net.Http.HttpMethod]::Get, "http://foobar/")
    $cancellationToken = New-Object System.Threading.CancellationToken
    $null = $serviceCredentials.ProcessHttpRequestAsync($message, $cancellationToken).GetAwaiter().GetResult()
    $accessToken = $message.Headers.GetValues("Authorization").Split(" ")[1] # This comes out in the form "Bearer <token>"
    
    $accessToken
}
function GetHeaders
{
    param (
        [string]$AccessToken,
        [switch]$IncludeStatistics,
        [switch]$IncludeRender,
        [int]$ServerTimeout
    )
    
    $preferString = "response-v1=true"
    
    if ($IncludeStatistics)
    {
        $preferString += ",include-statistics=true"
    }
    
    if ($IncludeRender)
    {
        $preferString += ",include-render=true"
    }
    
    if ($ServerTimeout -ne $null)
    {
        $preferString += ",wait=$ServerTimeout"
    }
    
    $headers = @{
        "Authorization"          = "Bearer $accessToken";
        "prefer"                 = $preferString;
        "x-ms-app"               = "LogAnalyticsQuery.psm1";
        "x-ms-client-request-id" = [Guid]::NewGuid().ToString();
    }
    
    $headers
}


$json = '
{
    "type": "Usage",
    "timeframe": "TheLastMonth",
    "dataset": {
    "granularity": "Monthly",
    "aggregation": {
        "totalCost": {
        "name": "PreTaxCost",
        "function": "Sum"
        }
    },
    "grouping": [
        {
        "type": "Dimension",
        "name": "ResourceId"
        }
    ]
    }
}
'

<#
else
{
    $json = '
    {
      "type": "Usage",
      "timeframe": "MonthToDate",
      "dataset": {
        "granularity": "Daily",
        "aggregation": {
          "totalCost": {
            "name": "PreTaxCost",
            "function": "Sum"
          }
        },
        "grouping": [
          {
            "type": "Dimension",
            "name": "ResourceId"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
    '
    
}
#>

$subscriptionlist = Get-AzSubscription | where {$_.State -eq 'Enabled'}

$accessToken = GetAccessToken
$headers = GetHeaders $accessToken -IncludeStatistics:$null -IncludeRender:$null -ServerTimeout 1000
$i = 0
$c = 50
$b = 100
$subscriptionlist | foreach {
$i++
    $subid = $_.Id
    $subscriptionname = $_.name
    $uri = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subid/providers/Microsoft.CostManagement/query?api-version=2019-11-01"
    $response = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri $uri -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $headers -Method POST -Body $json
    write-host "$i . $subscriptionname" -ForegroundColor Green
    if($i -eq $b)


    $PreTaxvirtualmachineCostvalue = 0
    $PreTaxCost1 = 0
    (($response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json).properties.rows) | foreach {
        $costdata = $null
        $PreTaxCost = $null
        $BillingMonth = $null
        $ResourceId = $null
        $Currency = $null
        
        $costdata = $_
        $PreTaxCost = $costdata[0]
        $BillingMonth = $costdata[1]
        $ResourceId = $costdata[2]
        $Currency = $costdata[3]
        $resourceName = ($ResourceId -split '/')[-1]
        $Resourcetype = (($ResourceId -split '/providers/')[1] -split '/')[0..1] -join '/'

        $PreTaxvirtualmachineCostvalue = $PreTaxvirtualmachineCostvalue + $PreTaxCost
        
        $PreTaxCost1 = ([math]::Round($PreTaxCost, 2)) + $PreTaxCost1
        
        
    }
```

I want to find out the cost of azure resources and I have created the above query. I want to convert the json data into excel and along with that I also want to add the below data into the query  Application_Name
Application_Owner
Business_Owner
Cost_Code
Environment_Name
Location
Resource group
Subscription

Please help me on the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the below snippet inside your foreach statement  `(($response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json).properties.rows) | foreach {........ in addition to your code.

```
$item = New-Object PSCustomObject
$item | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "PreTax Cost"  -NotePropertyValue $PreTaxCost
$item | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Billing Month"  -NotePropertyValue $BillingMonth 
$item | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Resource Id"  -NotePropertyValue  $ResourceId
$item | Export-Csv -Path D:\Output.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation
```

Basically, you creating a object with single row of value for multiple columns and exporting the same to excel. In an iteration process, all the data will be appended to the excel as a csv file.